# Converting string data to C# decimal

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Exporting a coordinate system to PRJ writes values of datum parameters with full ... The coordinate system dialog shows the full name of the selected datum in a .... (Fix) Parsing an Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY value no longer crashes on a ... sometimes creates an invalid table if the fields were taken from another table object.

Comment: just divide x by 10^positions and multiply by -1 if sign == "-"

Comment: Okay, so go ahead and make the method. It sounds like you're asking someone to write it for you. Can you add what you've tried?

Comment: `"Not found in Microsoft documentation."` - Correct, Microsoft will have no documentation for a custom method that you need to write for your project.  As an aside, I recommend creating this as an extension method on `decimal` instead of just a helper method in the current class, that way it can be more easily re-used elsewhere in your code.

Comment: `return x/Math.Pow(10, positions) * (sign.equals("-") ? -1 : 1);`

Comment: OldProgrammer and Wizche, many thanks!

Comment: @Wizche Remember that `Math.Pow` works with `double`, not `decimal`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks, I left decimal to double conversion as exercise on purpose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting a coordinate system to PRJ writes values of datum parameters with full ... The coordinate system dialog shows the full name of the selected datum in a .... (Fix) Parsing an Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY value no longer crashes on a ... sometimes creates an invalid table if the fields were taken from another table object.